# How do i cancel a timeout if a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a layout with some buttons, and I want after one of them is pushed to cancel the timeout, with the code that I have now I press one of the buttons and it redirects me to another activity but the timer dons't stop and after the 3 seconds it redirects me again, how do I cancel the timer if one of the buttons is pressed? 
This is the timer:

```js
int timeout = 3000;  seconds

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
        Intent homepage = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
    }
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and you will find a `Timer.cancel()`.
Keep a reference to the timer and call that whenever you want to make it stop.

> void cancel()
>
> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.

Example:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
});
```